# CiviCRM Scheduled Jobs Timezone Confusion

Tags: cron, scheduled-job, timezone

I am running a CiviCRM deployment in a GNU\Linux environment. When comparing the times reported by https://example.com/civicrm/admin/job (Settings - Scheduled Jobs) with https://example.com/civicrm/admin/joblog (Settings - Scheduled Jobs Log), the times reported are different.

In the first, the jobs overview, times seem to be reported in Drupal's timezone.  In the second, Scheduled Jobs Log, times seem to be reported in the user's timezone.  Is this intentional or a bug?

PHP version 7.3.8
Drupal version 7.67
CiviCRM version 5.18.2

The server's time zone is CEST
The Drupal time zone is Europe/London
My user's time zone is Europe/Berlin

I have tried to reproduce this in demo systems, but the ones I tried, understandably, restrict admin settings.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This question is now resolved.  It is not a bug, but a server misconfiguration.  I am adding the resolution here for posterity.

It turns out the issue was caused by the server being set to Europe/Berlin, but PHP-FPM defaulting to UTC.

Setting PHP-FPM to Europe/Berlin through its configuration file solved the issue.